New Exhaust Fan + EOL Switch Issues
Got a bit of an issue attempting to install new exhaust fans in both of my older house bathrooms. Dealing with two End of Line Switches for both fixtures fed from the outlet (in wall connection since both fixtures butt up to each other and outlets are close).
I'd prefer not to use another EOL setup and correct the wiring while I'm doing all this work. I'm thinking the best option is to cut and splice into the wiring from Line In to GFCI Receptacle, take it to the Bathroom #1 switch, and feed both Fixture #1 and Exhaust Fan from there.  Same with Bathroom #2 except from the line to Regular Receptacle to Master Bathroom.
I would cut back the old Fixture #1/2 wiring in the wall and only connect the GFCI to the Regular Receptacle
Thoughts and suggestions?


What's bothering you with having the switches at the end of the line?

There is nothing wrong with "EOL" switches. The catch though is that where such switches used to be 2 wires (plus ground), now they require neutral so that you can have a smart switch, even if you don't need it right now. Which means you usually need 3 wires (plus ground) where the rest of the circuit only needs 2 wires.

I'm trying to add another switch at each switch location (individual timer switches for the fans), which is why I don't think the EOL setup will work. Wouldn't I have to end up running another wire from the Fixture to the switch to get power anyway? Since the current setup uses the hot and neutral (black taped hot) to turn on and off the fixtures only.
